# Get values of a multidimensional array (Wordpress Settings)

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Unfortunately I am not the best with PHP.. Currently I am working on a WordPress Template for educational reasons. An aspect of the site should be a customer friendly way of editing the big slider on the frontpage.

I decided to make use of the settings page as wordpress admin using a solid working "builder" which allows you creating different types of pages in the theme settings without doing everything on your own.

**--IMPORTANT - Question starts here--**

So I thought taking a mutlidimensional array would be quite nice to store 3 elements for each slide. 1 Upload field for the image, 1 textfield for the title and 1 to store an URL.

[image]

While this is totally ok. I can't figure out how to get the values stored there. For some reason i can't access the  array with a foreach loop.

The code:

```
// Tab Two -  Section Two
// ------------------------//
$settings['Slider']['Slider Einstellungen'] = array('info' => 'Hier kannst du bis zu 5 Slider definieren. Die Bilder muss genau 2000 x 500 Pixel groß sein und der Titel darf nicht länger als 150 Zeichen lang sein, um optimal dargestellt zu werden.');

$fields = array();

$my_multi_fields = array();

$my_multi_fields[] = array(
    'type'  => 'upload',
    'name'  => 'slide_image',
    'label' => 'Slider Bild',           
    );

$my_multi_fields[] = array(
    'type'  => 'text',
    'name'  => 'slide_title',
    'label' => 'Titel'      
    );

$my_multi_fields[] = array(
    'type'  => 'text',
    'name'  => 'slide_url',
    'label' => 'URL'
    );

$fields[] = array(
    'type'  => 'multi',
    'name'  => 'slide_multi',
    'label' => 'Slider Optionen',
    'id' => 'slide_multi', // (optional, will default to name)
    'limit' => 5, // (optional, will default to unlimited)
    'fields' => $my_multi_fields
    );

$settings['Slider']['Slider Einstellungen']['fields'] = $fields;
```

Given this, I would like to get the 3 field of each element to create 1 slide for our slidepreview on the frontpage.
Please let me know if you need any further information!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($fields as $field) {
    // Start slide
    foreach($field['fields'] as $element) {
        // $element['type'];
        // $element['name'];
        // $element['label'];
    }
    // End slide
}
```